# Using groovy to match end of string

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I'm using Jenkins and want to match all buildable jobs whose names end in `_TEST` but can't get it to match via regex.

I have tried several ways but haven't been able to get it to match via groovy.

Comment: Can you add the code that you've tried? it will help us a lot to answer your question precisely.

Comment: Regex or Groovy? They are so not the same thing! [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is an expression syntax for doing string search/compare. [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) is a full programming language.

Comment: I started using a regex expression to match it within a groovy script.  Later I ran accross the ensWith() function and that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An equivalent, but far more concise solution than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442693/2648) is

```
import hudson.model.*

def list = Hudson.instance
                 .items
                 .findAll { it.buildable && it.name.endsWith("_TEST") }
                 .collect { it.name }
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of that.  how can I get it to give me just the job name?  output looks like this:     hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@756efc2e[Build_Job_TEST]

Comment: Rather than write a new answer, I edited this one to use 'collect' which will transform each object into its name. The formatting is slightly weird only to illustrate the code on Stack Overflow, and is not necessarily idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a different way around my problem.  Sorry, Monday mornings :)

```
import hudson.model.*

def list = []

for (item in Hudson.instance.items.findAll()) {
  if (item.name.endsWith("_TEST")) {
    if (item.isBuildable()) {
      list.push(item.name)
    }
  }
}

return list
```

Comment: The "groovy way" : `Hudson.instance.items.findAll { it.isBuildable() && it.name.endsWith("_TEST") }`